# How to import GTF file in recent versions of R

Tags: r, import, bioinformatics

I'm trying to upload GTF files into R, but seems that all of the previous methods are defunct.

```
import(file.gtf)
importgtf(file.gtf)
read.gtf(file.gtf)
```

Every single one, when I try to install the package for the function, I get the "package ‘package’ is not available for this version of R"
Is there an updated method for GTF files? The usual read.table() doesn't work either, as GTF files aren't a straightforward TSVs.

Example `.gtf` for reproducibility:
`https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vsbuffalo/bds-files/master/chapter-09-working-with-range-data/mm_GRCm38.75_protein_coding_genes.gtf`

Comment: What version of R are you using? Which packages are failing to install?

Comment: I think it's just a tab separated text file so you just have to skip the first two lines and it should read. I usually use `vroom::vroom()`.

Comment: As I said in the original question, it's not a TSV. The last column is basically a dictionary of additional values, which would be tedious to unpack by hand

Comment: Sorry - I was misread and was thinking of a .gct file.

Comment: Could try `rtracklayer::import()`.

Comment: That gives the error "Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘import’ for signature ‘"data.frame", "missing", "missing"’"

Comment: Without your specific .gtf it's hard to give much more help, although it might have to do with a dependency of rtracklayer. Is there a similarly structured .gtf file in the public domain somewhere you could share to make your problem reproducible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How should I deal with "package 'xxx' is not available (for R version x.y.z)" warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25721884/how-should-i-deal-with-package-xxx-is-not-available-for-r-version-x-y-z-wa)

Comment: The .gtf files are from this git repository (which is public) https://github.com/vsbuffalo/bds-files/tree/master/chapter-09-working-with-range-data

Answer (score 3):

It works for me with `rtracklayer::readGFF()`:

```r
library(rtracklayer)

g <- readGFF("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vsbuffalo/bds-files/master/chapter-09-working-with-range-data/mm_GRCm38.75_protein_coding_genes.gtf")

head(g)
#>   seqid         source type   start     end score strand phase
#> 1     1 protein_coding gene 3205901 3671498    NA      -    NA
#> 2     1 protein_coding gene 4343507 4360314    NA      -    NA
#> 3     1 protein_coding gene 4490928 4496413    NA      -    NA
#> 4     1 protein_coding gene 4773206 4785739    NA      -    NA
#> 5     1 protein_coding gene 4807788 4886770    NA      +    NA
#> 6     1 protein_coding gene 4857814 4897909    NA      +    NA
#>              gene_id gene_name    gene_source   gene_biotype
#> 1 ENSMUSG00000051951      Xkr4 ensembl_havana protein_coding
#> 2 ENSMUSG00000025900       Rp1        ensembl protein_coding
#> 3 ENSMUSG00000025902     Sox17        ensembl protein_coding
#> 4 ENSMUSG00000033845    Mrpl15 ensembl_havana protein_coding
#> 5 ENSMUSG00000025903    Lypla1 ensembl_havana protein_coding
#> 6 ENSMUSG00000033813     Tcea1 ensembl_havana protein_coding
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: That worked! What's the difference between GFF and GTF?

Comment: GTF is identical to GFF ver. 2 See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gene_transfer_format)